# How does android manage Music files uri?

Tags: android

I'm writing a music player and I'm using `ContentResolver` to get all music files the device's storage. The query retrieves an Id, title, album and artist and afterwards I store that in my local database.

Is it safe to use the Id that I get from the `ContentResolver` as a primary key for the tracks? Does android change the track's Id under any circumstance? What happens when the user manually deletes music files from his/her SDCard? How can I check that the id that I have in my database still references an existing file?

Comment: Do you really have to store the query result in your local DB? Duplication of data leads almost always to consistency issues.

Answer (score 0):

you already stored in Id, title, album and artist in local database .

one more thing you will store the path of files .so

when retrieve from database check the file in available in there location or not? if not means display alert to user

```
 File file = new File(filePath);
 if(file.exists())    
 {  
 //Do something to play or view details
 } 
else
 {
 // file may be deleted or moved by user  alert message here
 }
```